# CSS mouseenter and mouseover

Tags: css

I have been trying to handle mouse-enter and mouse-over event for a list element. I simple want to underline element when mouse enter , highlight element on mouseover/focus and returned to original on mouseleave event. Following code is working fine for underline part but not for highlighting part. There are two different operations which i want to handle on underline and focus accordingly.  please help.

```js
underlinefunction();
focusfunction();
```

```css
.nav li {
  display: block;
  padding-bottom: 8px;
}

.nav li a {
  position: relative;
  padding: 4px 2px 2px 0px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: blue;
  text-align: left;
}

.nav li a:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0px;
  height: 2px;
  width: 0;
  background: blue;
  text-align: left;
}

.nav li a:hover:after {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
    <ul class="nav">
      <li id="btnabout"><a href="#parallax"><strong>About</strong></a></li>
      <li id="btnportfolio"><a href="#portfolio"><strong>PortfolioPortfolio</strong></a></li>
      <li id="btncontact"><a href="#contact"><strong>Contact</strong></a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>


</html>
```

Comment: What have you tried? Are you looking for only css functionality? Focus on a link will mean it's clicked, is that what you want? This question is full of holes

Comment: You can check my answer or jsfiddle link.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the following code in css to highlight.

```
.nav li a:hover { 
     text-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.8); 
     -webkit-text-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
}
.nav li a:focus {
      text-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
      -webkit-text-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
}
```

> You can change `a:hover` or `a:focus` text-shadow color as you want.

```css
.nav li{
  display:block;
  padding-bottom:8px;
}
.nav li a{
  position:relative;  
  padding: 4px 2px 2px 0px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: blue;
  text-align: left; 
} 
.nav li a:hover {
  text-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
  -webkit-text-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
}
.nav li a:after{
  content: "";
  position:absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left:0px;  
  height: 2px;
  width:0;
  background: blue;
  text-align: left;
}
.nav li a:hover:after{
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
 <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
      <ul class="nav">
        <li id="btnabout"><a href="#parallax"><strong>About</strong></a></li>
        <li id="btnportfolio"><a href="#portfolio"><strong>PortfolioPortfolio</strong></a></li>
        <li id="btncontact"><a href="#contact"><strong>Contact</strong></a></li>
      </ul>
</div>
```

[**jsfiddle code here**](https://jsfiddle.net/mtztuf0j/)

Comment: Hi Lokesh, i want to underline when mouse enter, remove underline and highlight when hover (or focus) , back to original when mouse leave. what you suggested is not working as per exceptions and underline and highlight are getting in effect together on mouse enter.

Comment: Mouse enter is immediately followed by mouse over (a.k.a hover) which ends on mouse leave. Focus has nothing to do with this. You can make an animation on mouse enter so it underlines, removes underline and then highlights. Then on mouse leave remove highlight. Be aware than phones don't have a mouse and therefore no hover. Touch invokes click and focus. @usersam